# How do I check an installed Apache module in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, apache, bash, centos

I'm writing a Perl script to check and see if a module is currently installed for Apache. In Bash, I would use:

```
# httpd -M | grep fcgid
Syntax OK
fcgid_module (shared)
```

I want this to return a value of TRUE if that module exists and FALSE if it does not. I'm running into a problem though, because httpd -M always outputs "Syntax OK."

Here is what I 've got so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $FCGID = "";
if (`httpd -M | grep fcgid`) {
$FCGID = "enabled"
} else {
$FCGID = "disabled"
}
```

The IF always evaluates as true though.

About my configuration:

```
x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
# perl -v
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Open to suggestions. I'm pretty new at Perl and still kinda new at Bash scripting.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl 2>/dev/null -le 'my @list = qx(httpd -D DUMP_MODULES ); print "FCGI found" if ( grep { $_ =~ /fcgi/ } @list )  '
```

Comment: +1. But why not use `print "FCGI found" if grep /fcgi/, qx(httpd -D DUMP_MODULES);`?

Comment: Both of these still output "Syntax OK" =( Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just need to redirect the output and I was confused about how to do that.

```
$ httpd -M 2> /dev/null | grep fcgid_module
fcgid_module (shared)
```

So in PERL, I can evaluate that BASH expression and save it into a variable and test against the variable in the IF statement.

```
my $FCGI = "";
my $FCGI_mod = `httpd -M 2> /dev/null | grep fcgid_module`;
if ( $FCGI_mod eq "" ) {
$FCGI = "disabled"
} else {
$FCGI = "enabled"
}
```

It's not the prettiest, but it does what I need it to.

Thank you to those who looked into it!